# Change CheckBox value with custom class property

Tags: android, mobile, dart, flutter

This is my first time posting here, so I apologize if I did this incorrectly.

I made a custom class with a boolean field to control the CheckBox state/value:

```
class CustomModel {
static const TITLE_KEY = 'title';

  String id;
  String title;
  bool isChecked = false;

  void setIsChecked(bool isChecked) {
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
  }

  bool getIsChecked() {
    return isChecked;
  }

  CustomModel(Map<String, dynamic> ex) {
    title = ex[TITLE_KEY];
  }
}
```

In my CheckBox widget:

```
return new ExpansionTile(
                title: const Text('Title'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                children: snapshot.data.documents
                    .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  CustomModel ex = new CustomModel(document.data);
                  return new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(ex.title),
                    trailing: new Checkbox(
                        value: ex.getIsChecked(),
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                          setState(() {                             
                            ex.setIsChecked(value);
                          });
                        }),
                  );
                }).toList());
          }),
```

The CheckBox doesn't change (kind of flickers) when clicked. The logs show the CheckBox is "false" and then "true", but if I click on the same CheckBox again, the logs show "false" and then "true", so it doesn't seem to be updating the field.

I didn't have to set a value to "isChecked" when I did this in Java, but Flutter is throwing an error if I don't.

```
I/flutter ( 6408): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I/flutter ( 6408): The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 6408): _StreamBuilderBaseState>#0512c):
I/flutter ( 6408): 'package:flutter/src/material/checkbox.dart': Failed assertion: line 63: 'tristate || value !=
I/flutter ( 6408): null': is not true.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would look deeper into that `setState` function. I am not familiar with flutter; however, I do know in ReactJS, there is a function that appears to work in a similar fashion. Why does this matter? In ReactJS, the `setState` function may batch calls together in order to improve performance. This also means the calls might not work synchronously. Seeing as flutter's `setState` appears to similar, it might also batch calls.

Comment: Tyler - Thank you, I'm looking more into the setState function. I don't have experience with React, can you please explain batch calls vs. synchronous calls?

Comment: It's a generic topic. Basically a synchronous call means that call 1 will be dealt with before call 2. Call 2 before call 3, etc. A batch call would take call 1, call 2, and call 3 and deal with them a little later when they are actually required or on some other condition. It isn't guaranteed to be synchronous, so it could deal with the calls in a variety of orders. For example... call 2, call 3, then call 1.

Comment: You don't need to have experience with React. All I was trying to say is that React has a `setState` function and it may batch calls. Which means the calls may not be synchronous. Looking at your flutter's `setState` example, they appear to be similar. So flutter's `setState` may also batch calls or do something that may cause problems for beginners - Just like React. Essentially you just want to read on up the details of how `setState` works in flutter and if there are any bad practices that should be avoided and good practices that should be followed.

Comment: Tyler - Thank you for the explanation. I changed the code so it modifies a field in Firestore and updates accordingly based off the setState function. Do you know if my getters and setters are formatted properly? I'd like to not have Firestore hold this data as I have to clear it out after. After more testing, it looks like the value changes to "true" on press and then pulls the "false" value from the property immediately after.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your getters and setters; however, it's hard for me to tell since flutter may have some small syntax differences from the languages I'm use to. Putting that aside, grepLines has made an important point. Where are you calling your `return new ExpansionTile`? If it is in your build... Well see grepLine's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `return new ExpansionTile(..);` is in your the `build()` method of the `StatefulWidget` class. So when you call `setState()`, it will re-build widgets, which mean calling the `return new ExpansionTile(..);` again. Since your `CustomModel ex = new CustomModel(document.data);` will also be instantiate again, and `isChecked` will be false at that point. So the solution is to put all your build `CustomModel` list from firestore in [initState()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html).

This is the idea, (there may be some syntax errors because I write it straight on here).

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   State createState() => new MyWidgetState();  } 

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<CustomModel> customModels = []; 
  @override 
  initState() {
     //use listener to fetch data  
     Firestore.instance.collection("name").snapshots.listen((snapshot) {
        for (var doc in snapshot.documents) {
            CustomModel ex = new CustomModel(fieldname: doc['fieldname]);
            customModels.add(ex); 
        }

       }
    }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext) {
     return new ExpansionTile(
                title: const Text('Title'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
                children: customModels.map((CustomModel ex) {
                  return new ListTile(
                    title: new Text(ex.title),
                    trailing: new Checkbox(
                        value: ex.getIsChecked(),
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                          setState(() {                             
                            ex.setIsChecked(value);
                          });
                        }),
                  );
                }).toList());
          }),
     }    

}
```

Comment: Grep - Thank you very much for your explanation and code snippet. I understand the need to recreate the ExpansionTile widget in initState, but I don't understand how to create it or how to get a snapshot of Firestore in the initState function. I'm currently using StreamBuilder to take the snapshots and pull the data that flows through the widget tree down to the ExpansionTile widget. Do I need to create a custom ExpansionTile widget? Like Stateful and State classes and reference the custom widget in the tree?

Comment: @r3ck3z57 I have updated it my answer, you can use `Firestore.instance.collection('name').snapshot.listen((snapshot) {.. })` without having to use `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate y'all's help! I updated the code and it's working perfectly.